# Alamofire Void is not convertible to response

Tags: swift2, alamofire

This returns an error of '(_, _,) -> Void is not convertible to Response -> Void

This all began when i updated xCode to 7  My Alamofire requests return this error.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myURL,parameters:["action":"GetDetails"])
                .responseJSON { _,_,result in
```

Comment: And what is your question?  Also, a bit more context would be useful

Answer (score 0):

You are on the Alamofire 3.0.0-beta.1 pre-release. You should switch back to the Alamofire 2.0.2 release until we finalize all the documentation updates as well as the migration guide.